# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo ... java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm a newbie and i want to test an android project, I imported the project and its librairies to eclipse. It seams to be ok but when I run the project the errors in the LogCat below are shown.

I've red and tried the possible solutions in this site but it didn't work, can you help me please?

**here is my LogCat**

```
 03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363): Process: com.glabs.homegenie, PID: 1363
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.glabs.homegenie/com.glabs.homegenie.StartActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.glabs.homegenie.StartActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.glabs.homegenie-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.glabs.homegenie-1, /system/lib]]
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.glabs.homegenie.StartActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.glabs.homegenie-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.glabs.homegenie-1, /system/lib]]
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
    03-13 11:02:51.238: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     ... 11 more
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.glabs.homegenie"
    android:versionCode="18"
    android:versionName="1.0.16" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity
            android:name="com.glabs.homegenie.StartActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.glabs.homegenie.WebActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.glabs.homegenie.StartActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.glabs.homegenie.StartActivity" />>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.glabs.homegenie.widgets.CameraControlActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.glabs.homegenie.StartActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.glabs.homegenie.StartActivity" />>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="org.teleal.cling.android.AndroidUpnpServiceImpl"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Main Activity**

```
package com.glabs.homegenie;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.glabs.homegenie.adapters.GenericWidgetAdapter;
import com.glabs.homegenie.client.Control;
import com.glabs.homegenie.client.data.Event;
import com.glabs.homegenie.client.data.Group;
import com.glabs.homegenie.client.data.Module;
import com.glabs.homegenie.client.eventsource.EventSourceListener;
import com.glabs.homegenie.fragments.ErrorDialogFragment;
import com.glabs.homegenie.fragments.GroupsViewFragment;
import com.glabs.homegenie.fragments.MacroRecordDialogFragment;
import com.glabs.homegenie.fragments.SettingsFragment;
import com.glabs.homegenie.util.AsyncImageDownloadTask;
import com.glabs.homegenie.util.UpnpManager;
import com.glabs.homegenie.util.VoiceControl;
import com.glabs.homegenie.widgets.ModuleDialogFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 */
public class StartActivity extends FragmentActivity implements EventSourceListener {

    //variable for checking Voice Recognition support on user device
    private static final int VR_REQUEST = 1;

    public final String PREFS_NAME = "HomeGenieService";
    private GroupsViewFragment mGroupsViewFragment;
    private LinearLayout mLoadingCircle;
    private TextView mLoaderText;
    private TextView mDonateText;
    private TextView mEventText;
    private TextView mEventTime;
    private ImageView mEventIcon;

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Menu _actionmenu;
    private boolean _ispaused = false;
    public boolean _islogovisible = true;
    private VoiceControl _voicecontrol;
    private UpnpManager _upnpmanager;

    private Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mGroupsViewFragment.UpdateCurrentGroupModules();
            Fragment widgetpopup = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("WIDGET");
            if (widgetpopup != null && widgetpopup instanceof ModuleDialogFragment) {
                ((ModuleDialogFragment) widgetpopup).refreshView();
            }
        }
    };

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Remove title bar
        //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && getActionBar() != null) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        mLoadingCircle = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.loadingCircle);
        mLoaderText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tapoptions);
        mDonateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.donatetext);
        mEventText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eventStatus);
        mEventTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eventTime);
        mEventIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eventIcon);

        mGroupsViewFragment = new GroupsViewFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentMain, mGroupsViewFragment, "Groups");
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        _ispaused = false;

        if (_upnpmanager == null) {
            _upnpmanager = new UpnpManager(this);
            _upnpmanager.bind();
        }

        // Connect to HomeGenie service
        if (Control.getGroups() == null && Control.getModules() == null) {
            homegenieConnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        _ispaused = true;

        if (mHandler != null) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }
        if (_upnpmanager != null) {
            _upnpmanager.unbind();
            _upnpmanager = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //outState.putString("WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_KEY", "WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_VALUE");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
/*        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            return true;
        }
        else*/
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        homegenieDisconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void homegenieConnect() {
        // Reset groups fragment
        mGroupsViewFragment.setGroups(new ArrayList<Group>());
        // Read preferences, if empty let's show the settings dialog
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        if (settings.getString("serviceAddress", "127.0.0.1").equals("127.0.0.1")) {
            showLogo();
            showSettings();
        } else {
            loaderShow();
            if (mHandler != null) {
                mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            }
            final StartActivity hgcontext = this;
            Control.setServer(
                    settings.getString("serviceAddress", "127.0.0.1"),
                    settings.getString("serviceUsername", "admin"),
                    settings.getString("servicePassword", "")
            );
            Control.connect(new Control.UpdateGroupsAndModulesCallback() {
                @Override
                public void groupsAndModulesUpdated(boolean success) {
                    if (success) {
                        mGroupsViewFragment.setGroups(Control.getGroups());
                        hideLogo();
                        //
                        if (_voicecontrol == null) {
                            _voicecontrol = new VoiceControl(hgcontext);
                        }
                    } else {
                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        if (!_ispaused) {
                            if (fm.findFragmentByTag("SETTINGS") == null || !fm.findFragmentByTag("SETTINGS").isVisible()) {
                                if (fm.findFragmentByTag("ERROR") == null || !fm.findFragmentByTag("ERROR").isVisible()) {
                                    ErrorDialogFragment fmWidget = new ErrorDialogFragment();
                                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                                    fragmentTransaction.add(fmWidget, "ERROR");
                                    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    updateGroupModules();
                    loaderHide();
                }
            }, this);
        }
    }

    public void homegenieDisconnect() {
        Control.disconnect();
    }

    public void hideLogo() {
        _islogovisible = false;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(0.8f, 0);
                fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); //and this
                fadeOut.setStartOffset(0);
                fadeOut.setDuration(500);
                //
                AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
                animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                RelativeLayout ivlogo = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.logo);
                ivlogo.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        });
    }

    public void showLogo() {
        _islogovisible = true;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 0.8f);
                fadeIn.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); //and this
                fadeIn.setStartOffset(0);
                fadeIn.setDuration(500);
                //
                AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
                animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                RelativeLayout ivlogo = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.logo);
                ivlogo.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        });
    }

    public void loaderShow() {
        //mLoadingCircle.setAlpha(0.25f);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLoadingCircle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mLoaderText.setText("Connecting to HomeGenie");
            }
        });
    }

    public void loaderHide() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDonateText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mLoadingCircle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mLoaderText.setText("Tap Options menu for Settings");
            }
        });
    }

    public void showSettings() {
        SettingsFragment fmWidget = new SettingsFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(fmWidget, "SETTINGS");
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        //fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    public void openMacroRecordMenu() {
        MacroRecordDialogFragment fmWidget = new MacroRecordDialogFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(fmWidget, "MACRORECORD");
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    public void updateGroupModules() {
        if (Control.getGroups() != null && Control.getModules() != null) {
            if (mHandler != null) {
                mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            }
            mHandler = new Handler();
            //startRepeatingTask();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, 300);
        }
    }

    public void showOptionsMenu() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    openOptionsMenu();
                    if (_actionmenu != null) {
                        _actionmenu.performIdentifierAction(R.id.menu_system, 0);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    showSettings();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (_actionmenu == null) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_group, menu);
            _actionmenu = menu;
            //
            _actionmenu.findItem(R.id.action_recognition).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    if (_voicecontrol != null)
                    {
                        _voicecontrol.startListen();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to instantiate Voice Control.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }
        mGroupsViewFragment.UpdateCurrentGroupMenu();
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        Intent browserIntent;
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_quit:
                finish();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_settings:
                showSettings();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_admin:
                // Read preferences
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                String serviceAddress = settings.getString("serviceAddress", "");
                if (!serviceAddress.equals("")) {
                    browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://" + serviceAddress));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
                return true;

            case R.id.action_help:
                browserIntent = new Intent(this, WebActivity.class);
                browserIntent.putExtra("URL", Uri.parse("http://www.homegenie.it/docs").toString());
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return true;

            //case R.id.action_refresh:
            //    return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
        super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);
    }


    public Menu getActionMenu() {
        return _actionmenu;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSseConnect() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSseEvent(final Event event) {

        if (event.Property.equals("Program.Status")) return;

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateGroupModules();
                //
                String displayName = event.Domain + "." + event.Source;
                Module module = Control.getModule(event.Domain, event.Source);
                boolean filtered = isFilteredEvent(event);
                if (module != null && !filtered) {
                    final String imageUrl = Control.getHgBaseHttpAddress() + GenericWidgetAdapter.getModuleIcon(module);
                    if (mEventIcon.getTag() == null || !mEventIcon.getTag().equals(imageUrl) && !(mEventIcon.getDrawable() instanceof AsyncImageDownloadTask.DownloadedDrawable)) {
                        AsyncImageDownloadTask asyncDownloadTask = new AsyncImageDownloadTask(mEventIcon, true, new AsyncImageDownloadTask.ImageDownloadListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void imageDownloadFailed(String url) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void imageDownloaded(String url, Bitmap downloadedImage) {
                                mEventIcon.setTag(imageUrl);
                            }
                        });
                        asyncDownloadTask.download(imageUrl, mEventIcon);
                    }
                    displayName = module.getDisplayName() + " (" + module.getDisplayAddress() + ")";
                }
                //
                if (!filtered)
                {
                    mEventText.setText(displayName + "\n" + event.Property + " " + event.Value.replace("<br>", "\n").replace("<br/>", "\n").replace("<br />", "\n"));
                    mEventTime.setText(DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getApplicationContext()).format(event.Timestamp));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onSseError(String error) {

    }

    private boolean isFilteredEvent(Event event) {
        boolean isFiltered = false;
        if (event.Property.equals("Meter.Watts"))
        {
            try
            {
                double value = Double.parseDouble(event.Value);
                if (value == 0) isFiltered = true;
            } catch (Exception e) { }
        }
        return isFiltered;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: no i'm using eclipse Luna

Comment: Have you tried a clean build?

Comment: Try changing the `com.glabs.homegenie.StartActivity` to `.StartActivity` in the AndroidManifest.xml and see if it makes a difference

Comment: yes tried it, i even close eclipse and restart it

Comment: @AdelBousselmi Can I know what is this path? DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.glabs.homegenie-1.apk"]